# Manually adding to an HTML range input gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const sliderInput = document.querySelector('input');
const sliderTracker = document.querySelector('.slider-tracker span');

const minusBtn = document.querySelector('.minus');
const plusBtn = document.querySelector('.plus');

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(sliderInput.value)
  sliderInput.value -= 0.25;
  renderTooltip();
  console.log(sliderInput.value)
});

plusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(sliderInput.value)
  sliderInput.value += 0.25;
  renderTooltip();
  console.log(sliderInput.value)
})

function renderTooltip() {
  sliderTracker.innerHTML = sliderInput.value
}
```

```html
<input class="slider" type="range" name="slider" min="0.5" max="3" value="1.5" step="0.25">
<div class="slider-tracker"><span>0.5</span></div>

<button class="minus">subtract</button>
<button class="plus">add</button>
```

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/Cdplourde/pen/qLEXVV)

I'm having issues manually changing the values of a range input.

If I subtract from the value, everything works as expected (it decrements the value I specified correctly), however when I try to **add** to the input I'm getting issues. It either maxes out at 1.75, or sometimes jumps all the way to 3 while skipping steps.

Can anyone clue me in on what's happening here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the value is a string so you are adding a string plus a number. So you need to change the string to a number, than add it.

```js
const sliderInput = document.querySelector('input');
const sliderTracker = document.querySelector('.slider-tracker span');

const minusBtn = document.querySelector('.minus');
const plusBtn = document.querySelector('.plus');

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(sliderInput.value)
  sliderInput.value -= 0.25;
  renderTooltip();
  console.log(sliderInput.value)
});

plusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(typeof sliderInput.value, sliderInput.value, )
  sliderInput.value = +sliderInput.value + 0.25;
  renderTooltip();
  console.log(sliderInput.value)
})

function renderTooltip() {
  sliderTracker.innerHTML = sliderInput.value
}
```

```html
<input class="slider" type="range" name="slider" min="0.5" max="3" value="1.5" step="0.25">
<div class="slider-tracker"><span>0.5</span></div>

<button class="minus">subtract</button>
<button class="plus">add</button>
```

Comment: Ahh yep makes total sense. This fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's because sometimes you bump into the min and max limits, and the control won't reflect them, but the value persists in memory, so then the next time you click it, it still has to increment or decrement for you to get back into range.

You can solve this by building your min/max into your increment/decrement logic.

```js
const sliderInput = document.querySelector('input');
const sliderTracker = document.querySelector('.slider-tracker span');

const minusBtn = document.querySelector('.minus');
const plusBtn = document.querySelector('.plus');

var value = 1.5;

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(sliderInput.value)
  value = Math.max(0.5, value - 0.25)
  sliderInput.value = value;
  renderTooltip();
  console.log(sliderInput.value)
});

plusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(sliderInput.value)
  value = Math.min(3, value + 0.25);
  sliderInput.value = value;
  renderTooltip();
  console.log(sliderInput.value)
})

function renderTooltip() {
  sliderTracker.innerHTML = sliderInput.value
}
```

```html
<input class="slider" type="range" name="slider" min="0.5" max="3" value="1.5" step="0.25">
<div class="slider-tracker"><span>0.5</span></div>

<button class="minus">subtract</button>
<button class="plus">add</button>
```